# Powershell question about parsing the tag values in Get-AzVm

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm attempting to load individual tag key and value records per VM using the Get-AzVm cmdlet. The values are stored like:

"Tags               : {"Purpose":"SQL Server","Test":"Value"}"

I want to load them like:

VMID, VMName, Key, Value

No amount of searching or testing with ForEach, ForEach-Object or loading in to a hash is working as the results are always null, but what is loaded in to a variable is not. I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Hi DBA-One, could you clarify your question?   Where do you want to load your tags too?  And what do you mean by saying the values are stored?  Where are they stored?  Are you referring to the output of the Get-AzVm cmdlet?  Could you edit your question to clarify?  Cheers!

Comment: Could you please provide your script?

Comment: $vm_list = Get-AzVM
foreach ($name in $vm_list)
    {
    $tags = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $name.ResourceGroupName -Name $name.Name).Tags
    ForEach($tag in $tags)
                    {
                    write-host $Tag
                    }
    }

Comment: What I just posted is a simplified version. In the data, the tags are stored like "{"Purpose":"SQL Server","Test":"Value"}".

Answer (score 3):

```
    $vm_list = Get-AzVM -Name #######
foreach ($name in $vm_list)
    {
    $_ = $vm_list.tags.GetEnumerator() | 
    ForEach-Object{
                $k = $_.key
                $v = $_.value
                Write-Host $tagkeys.VMID, $tagkeys.Name, $k, $v
                }
   }
```

There is more to the script, but this is what I have working now. Using enumerator, I would have expected to need to reference the objects as {0} and {1}.